# Cannot get products in Magento 1.6.1.0's SOAP API's CatalogProductList when I have more than 25 products

Tags: c#, magento

I’m trying to list all my products with the SOAP v2 interface in C# (.Net 4.0, VS 2010), using the WS-I compliant, WSDL generated version of the SOAP interface in Magento 1.6.1.0.

I can retrieve products normally with my code (appended below) when I have fewer than 25 products. However, when I have 25 products or more, I get an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML 
document (333, 2). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occu 
rred. The following elements are not closed: complexObjectArray, result, ns1:cat 
alogProductListResponseParam, SOAP-ENV:Body, SOAP-ENV:Envelope. Line 333, positi 
on 2. 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read() 
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent() 
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMagent 
oService.Read32_catalogProductEntity(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) 
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMagent 
oService.Read121_Item() 
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer86.De 
serialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, St 
ring encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, St 
ring encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClie 
ntMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCal 
l) 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodN 
ame, Object[] parameters) 
at MagentoAPITest.mage.MagentoService.catalogProductList(String sessionId, fi 
lters filters, String store) in ....\technology\c#\MagentoAPITest 
\MagentoAPITest\Web References\mage\Reference.cs:line 1982 
at MagentoAPITest.magentoHelper.GetProducts() in ....\technolo 
gy\c#\MagentoAPITest\MagentoAPITest\magentoHelper.cs:line 62 
at MagentoAPITest.Program.Main(String[] args) in ....g\technolo 
gy\c#\MagentoAPITest\MagentoAPITest\Program.cs:line 30 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It doesn’t seem to matter what kind of products I’m creating; I’m always thrown this error.

I can continue to add products; when I do so, the error changes slightly to (in the case of 50 products)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML 
document (666, 2). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: complexObjectArray, result, ns1:catalogProductListResponseParam, SOAP-ENV:Body, SOAP-ENV:Envelope. Line 666, position 2.
```

I presume that this means that Magento is sending the appropriate data; however, I'm suspecting that C# isn't parsing the data correctly?

For reference, I retrieve my products via:

```
 public List<mage.catalogProductEntity> GetProducts()
        {
            //var result = ms.call(sessionID, "catalog_product.list", null);



            // retrieve products  
            mage.filters filter = new mage.filters();
            mage.catalogProductEntity[] products = new mage.catalogProductEntity[1];
            try
            {

                products = ms.catalogProductList(sessionID, filter, "");
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                System.Xml.XmlException xe = (System.Xml.XmlException ) e.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(xe.SourceUri);
                throw;
            }
            foreach (mage.catalogProductEntity product in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(product.product_id + ", "
                    + product.name + ", " 
                    + product.type + ", " 
                    + product.sku + ", "
                    + product.set + "");

            }
            List<mage.catalogProductEntity> ProductsList = new List<mage.catalogProductEntity>(products);
            return ProductsList;
        }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

We have magento enterprise and were able to find a fix WITHOUT modifying the core!  It is so simple its sad.  Our issue is that our php poutput is gzipped like a lot of php servers output.  in C# OR PHP use the enable decomression flag on the web service:

```
mservice.EnableDecompression = true;
```

where mservice is your service name.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what's happening is that the request is timing out either because of php, or the db(guessing mysql).

What you can do to test that, is where you have this line:
 ms.catalogProductList(sessionID, filter, "");
set the filter to pull one specific productID.  then just loop over the product list call as you increment the productId.
(something like "productId eq 12")

If all the products can be pulled this way then it's likely a timeout/resource issue on your mage server. If not, then it's likely something related to a specific product.

Assuming you can get them one-by-one, then the next step from there is to cut down the number of calls to product list by using a filter on productID > X and ProductID < X + 10(or whatever number you like).

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to a magento Issue
try to search "\n" and replace by "" in

\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api\Model\Server\Wsi\Adapter\Soap.php
(a previus Backup is recomended ;P )
(the best aproach would be to exted the involved classes but this is a fast test only...)

Answer (score 0):

The issue definitely is in  **\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api\Model\Server\Wsi\Adapter\Soap.php**

I had this problem in C# for weeks!!!
It doesnt really understand **\n**. Remove them, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Magento 1.6.2.0 and VisualBasic. After removing the all unneeded white space it works fine. 
It seems the `"\n"` isn't compatible with `crlf` line breaks in the Windows world (perhaps it should be `"\r\n"` if you want to have line breaks).

Instead of adjusting the core file it's better to rewrite the class within your own module.

Add to your `MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<!-- other stuff -->
<global>
    <models>    
        <api>
            <rewrite>
                <server_wsi_adapter_soap>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Server_WSI_Adapter_Soap</server_wsi_adapter_soap>
            </rewrite>
        </api>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Create your own adapter class in `MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Server/WSI/Adapter/Soap.php` with the adjusted run() method:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Server_WSI_Adapter_Soap extends Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap
{
public function run(){

    $apiConfigCharset = Mage::getStoreConfig("api/config/charset");

    if ($this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('wsdl') !== null) {
        $wsdlConfig = Mage::getModel('api/wsdl_config');
        $wsdlConfig->setHandler($this->getHandler())
            ->init();
        $this->getController()->getResponse()
            ->clearHeaders()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
            ->setBody(
                    preg_replace(
                        '/(\>\s+\<)/i', // changed to match all whitespace enclosed by > and <
                        "><",           // replace it with just ><
                        str_replace(
                                '<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>',
                                "<soap:operation soapAction=\"\" />",   // removed the \n 
                                str_replace(
                                        '<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>',
                                        "<soap:body use=\"literal\" />",    // removed the \n 
                                        preg_replace(
                                            '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                                            '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                                            $wsdlConfig->getWsdlContent()
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    )
            );
    } else {
        try {
            $this->_instantiateServer();

            $this->getController()->getResponse()
                ->clearHeaders()
                ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
                ->setBody(
                    preg_replace(
                        '/(\>\s+\<)/i',     // same here
                        "><",               // and here
                        str_replace(
                                '<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>',
                                "<soap:operation soapAction=\"\" />",   // removed the \n 
                                str_replace(
                                        '<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>',
                                        "<soap:body use=\"literal\" />", // removed the \n 
                                        preg_replace(
                                            '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                                            '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                                            $this->_soap->handle()
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    )
                );
        } catch( Zend_Soap_Server_Exception $e ) {
            $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
        } catch( Exception $e ) {
            $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

This will output clean XML with no unneeded characters that cause strange errors.